# DoSing my Home Network with only a Public IP address

Tags: network, ddos, denial-of-service, ports

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Client Host Name |.. IP Address ..|.... MAC Address ...|  
| Desktop-Home ....|  192.168.1.100 | 00:19:D1:EA:03:68  |    
| GT-S5380K .......|  192.168.1.105 | B8:C6:8E:4D:12:B1  |
```

Here you can see 2 things connected to my network (as seen in the DHCP Client table): My PC and my phone. Is there any way that I can get the port number of my phone connected to my public IP address?

I am asking this because I want to know if it is possible to (D)DoS a Network. Let's say my public IP address is 117.202.xxx.xxx. Is there a way to (D)DoS that network (using LOIC) such a way that my 2 devices wont be able to use the internet? Or is it possible to DoS only one port on the network (only my phone or pc)?

If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Please, you don't need caps ("ONLY MY PHONE OR PC")

Comment: You might want to read about LOIC and DDoS attacks before you even think about doing anything. What you're wanting to do isn't called a DDoS attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes, there is a way to DoS that network so that neither device is able to access the internet" - DoS the router through its outside interface in order to saturate outside comms. Both devices will still be able to communicate with each other.

If you want to prevent your computer or phone from doing anything, you will need significantly more bandwidth *and* all hosts you use, unless port-forwarding, will need to reside on the local network.

I'd strongly recommend you look up what DoS actually is. You mention LOIC - it's actually a very specific tool, definitely not the only one, and definitely not the best... especially considering that trivial firewall config can completely thwart it. Why are you so interested in it, anyway?

P.S: Nice samsung galaxy wave.